# ListContourPlot3D doesn't use all points

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, mesh

**Edited** thanks to @Kuba:

In the following example, ListContourPlot3D accepts an array of points spaced at intervals 0.1 apart throughout the volume, but seems to choose an arbitrary number of points for generating a mesh. Setting `MaxPlotPoints` explicitly works to a limited extent. How can I force it to use all points without specifying that number by hand?

```
gauss = Partition[
   Flatten[Table[{i, j, k, Exp[-i^2 - j^2]}, {i, -2, 2, 0.1}, {j, -2, 
      2, 0.1}, {k, -2, 2, 0.1}]], 4];

    GraphicsRow[{
  ListContourPlot3D[gauss, Contours -> {0.5}, 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}],
  ListContourPlot3D[gauss, Contours -> {0.5}, 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
   MaxPlotPoints -> 20],
  ListContourPlot3D[gauss, Contours -> {0.5}, 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
   MaxPlotPoints -> Infinity]
  }, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

**Edit** thanks to @Rahul:

For a 3D array (with the right order of indices) we get the right behavior. Does this mean the 4D syntax constructs the mesh in a fundamentally different way?

```
gauss = Table[Exp[-i^2 - j^2], {k, -2, 2, 0.1}, {j, -2, 2, 0.1}, {i, -2, 2, 0.1}];

ListContourPlot3D[gauss, Contours -> {0.5}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, DataRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

**Edit** thanks to @Szabolcs:

Increasing `MaxPlotPoints` constructs the mesh with some strange regularities (and appears to slow it down):

```
GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[
  Table[ListContourPlot3D[gauss, Contours -> {0.5}, 
    ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
    MaxPlotPoints -> i, ImageSize -> 200, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Style[StringJoin["MaxPlotPoints->", ToString[i]], 16, Bold]], {i,
     18, 38, 4}], 3, 3, 1, Null], ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Comment: @Nasser [ListContourPlot3D](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListContourPlot3D.html?q=ListContourPlot3D&lang=en) dimensions are ok.

Comment: `MaxPlotPoints -> 20` makes it look good. But it seems the the more is not necessarily the better.

Comment: @Kuba Right, `MaxPlotPoints->Infinity` doesn't do anything! (Gosh, it took me a while to get this comment right.)

Comment: If you make the input data just be a three-dimensional array, `gauss = Table[Exp[-i^2 - j^2], {i, -2, 2, 0.1}, {j, -2, 2, 0.1}, {k, -2, 2, 0.1}]`, then `ListContourPlot3D` uses all the values, but the orientation and scaling of the axes is off. You can fix the scaling with `DataRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}`, but not sure what to do about the orientation. http://i.stack.imgur.com/17ozK.png

Comment: There is a fundamental difference, in the flat list case the interpolation scheme first has to sort out the connectivity somehow. Note you get the exact same result (just as fast) if you plot `RandomSample[gauss, Length[gauss]]`

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but experimenting with `ListContourPlot` (which is much faster so more convenient to play with), it seems that with `MaxPlotPoints -> Infinity` it does in fact include *all* points in the simple examples I tried (maybe not in more complicated ones).  You can see this clearly if you use `Mesh->All`.  However, if I use `MaxPlotPoints -> 50`or some other high value like that, then it included *more* points than I gave it.  Probably it generates them using interpolation.  You can even control it using `InterpolationOrder`.

Comment: To answer your question about the array vs 4-tuple syntax, yes, it does construct the mesh in a fundamentally different way.  If you use the array version, it can take advantage of the regular structure of the grid and use any `InterpolationOrder`.  If you give it values at arbitrary locations in 3D space, it will compute a Delaunay tessellation first and use that as the basis of the interpolation (which I *think* is limited to 1st or 0th order).  So, I'm not sure what's going on, and I'm not saying that it does use all points in your example, but increasing MaxPlotPoints *generates* ...

Comment: ... some extra points, not just necessarily *include* all existing ones.  With a high value you'll be able to see the structure of the underlying grid and the cylinder will be jagged (pixelated-looking).  It it possible that what `ListContourPlot3D` does is simply use `Interpolation` and invoke `ContourPlot3D` on the result? Just a guess.

Comment: The key is probably in the Method option of ListContourPlot3D, the possible settings for which, as usual, are not documented ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, increasing MaxPlotPoints to a large but finite value seems to dramatically slow it down as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a work around, in case you need to work with the flat (unordered) data:

```
 interp = Interpolation[{#[[;; 3]], #[[4]]} & /@ gauss];
 ContourPlot3D[interp[x, y, z], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},Contours -> {.5}]
```

[image]

worth pointing out this seems to work fine for completely unordered data:

```
gauss = Table[
     Join[#, {Exp[-#[[1]]^2 - #[[2]]^2 ]}] &@ RandomReal[{-2.1, 2.1}, 3], {8000}];
interp = Interpolation[{#[[;; 3]], #[[4]]} & /@ gauss];
ContourPlot3D[interp[x, y, z], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Contours -> {.5}]
```

[image]

ListContoutPlot3D of the unordered data..

[image]

Comment: Great solution, thanks. For the random array, this method works, but I get `Interpolation::udeg: Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently only supported for InterpolationOrder->1 or InterpolationOrder->All. Order will be reduced to 1. >>` and the plot is much sloppier than yours. I assume it's because I'm running Mathematica 8.

Comment: @ninemileskid It is because you have specified `InterpolationOrder` other than `1`: such interpolation is supported only on structured grids even in v.9. If you wish to use higher order interpolation, you should use third-party packages: [Obtuse package](http://www.familydahl.se/mathematica/#Obtuse), [Non-Grid Interpolation Package](http://nongridinterpolation.web.fc2.com/).

Comment: Sorry - I get that warning with v9 as well. Since it worked I neglected to mention it.